# Dealing with multithreading in UI

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, user-interface

I am actually using sockets listeners in a Java program. 
The idea is to let my program run until it catches an external event. As soon as it catches it, I have to update my layout.

In order to let my application run while it was listening on a specific port, I did something like this :

```java
// new thread allows me to let my program continue
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(59090)) {
                    System.out.println("The server is running...");
                    // listening
                    while (true) {
                        try (Socket socket = listener.accept()) {
                            // catches event
                            System.out.println("event caught");
                            InputStream raw = socket.getInputStream();
                            headerData = getHeaders(raw);
                            // some code
                            // ...
                            // ...

                            // Update UI
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}.start();
```

The idea is that I constantly listen on the port 59090 and I execute my specific code once I use that port and that works well.

The problem now is when I catch an event. 
It seems that I can't act on the UI if I am not in the "main" Thread. Am I right ?
Is it possible to send an information to my "main thread" in order to tell it to update UI ? Otherwise is it possible to "switch" my main thread to this one ?

EDIT:

I've seen that in Android you could use AsyncTask and the method onPostExecute() allows to send informations to the UI thread.

onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

Is there an equivalent in Java?

Thank you

Comment: Almost every UI Framework has some kind of method that you can use to submit a Runnable to be executed on the UI Thread. In JavaFX it is `Platform.runLater(Runnable)`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately I don't think that I have something like that at disposal. I will check for a UI Thread existance

Comment: What do you use for your UI? Swing? AWT? JavaFX? JWT?

Comment: It is a "home Framework". A mix of xml files and "private" languages.
I will see if there is a thread management system somewhere and if something looks like that